# What does it means INRI in Jesus Cross?

Tags: life-of-jesus, history, cross

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does INRI stand for?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12003/what-does-inri-stand-for)

In Jesus Cross there is symbol like INRI, What does it exactly means and why they are keeping this still in cross any conditions or story behind this steel plate or this symbol in cross.Please refer the following location : [INRI in Cross](http://www.catholicdevotionnetwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/IMG_4007.jpg)

Comment: Iēsus Nazarēnus, Rēx Iūdaeōrum can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus,_King_of_the_Jews)

Comment: John, maybe you want to change your question to more specifically ask about the symbolism or story behind the plate (like was it metal?).  Asking what the initials stand for or are intended to stand for requires very little research to determine and as far as I know is consistent between denominations.

Answer (score 1):

IESVS NAZARENVS REX IVDAEORVM and it means jessus the nazarinean king of jews, it was wrote so that everyone could mock Him.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE!  You will find here that this SE is a lot different than Stackoverflow in that SO's custom is to have correct and fast answers.  In this SE, it is important to have supporting details, references, etc.  Please consider reviewing the [faq].  Answers such as the one you posted are often downvoted.  Not because they're wrong, but because they do not include references or point to a specific denomination.  There is a HUGE difference between having the "right" answer and a "good" answer here.  I look forward to your participation here!